# Specifying out params for Type.GetMethod

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm using reflection to get at the TryParse method info (upvote for the first person to guess why ;).

If I call:

```
typeof(Int32).GetMethod("Parse",
  BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
  null,
  new Type[] { typeof(string) },
  null);
```

I get a method back, but extending this slightly:

```
typeof(Int32).GetMethod("TryParse",
  BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
  null,
  new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(Int32) },
  null);
```

I get nothing back. My spidersense is telling me it's because the second parameter is an out parameter.

Anyone know what I've done wrong here?

Comment: "Anyone know what I've done wrong here?" - yeah, using reflection to call TryParse! ;)

Comment: You're probably trying to `TryParse` an arbitrary numeric type.  Don't.  `Convert.ChangeType` with a `catch` block will be faster.

Comment: @Khanzor: Yes, while using exceptions to control program flow is generally not a good practice because of the speed penalty, reflection is not particularly quick either. It's hard to say either is "correct" or "best practice". Clearly your usage case is non-standard here. And I'm not very good at guessing why. If you tell us, we might be able to propose a better solution.

Comment: @Cody - I'm getting around the fact that there is no such thing as an interface to represent types that have a TryParse method (something like ITryParseable), by staticly collecting all the method infos into a cache and doing a lookup in a generic TryParse method. E.g. "true".TryParse<bool>().

Comment: @Cody - I'd also argue that neither are "best practice". I could have a myriad of `if` statements doing tryparses based on type, I just think my method is a little more elegant, if a touch slower.

Comment: Side note (late update), referring to *'I'm getting around the fact that there is no such thing as an interface to represent types that have a TryParse method'*:
As of .NET 7.0 (which obviously arrived after the question was asked) there's now indeed an [IParsable<TSelf>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iparsable-1?view=net-8.0) interface, allowing to restrict to types that offer the required functionality. See, too, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472792/does-c-sharp-contain-iparsablet-or-itryparsablet).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try this

```
typeof(Int32).GetMethod("TryParse",
  BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
  null,
  new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(Int32).MakeByRefType() },
  null);
```

Comment: I note that the MS documentation includes and example for c# which uses c syntax for this. Your example works, their's doesn't.

Answer (score 7):

Like @Jab's but a little shorter:

```
var tryParseMethod = typeof(int).GetMethod(nameof(int.TryParse),
                                           new[]
                                           {
                                               typeof(string),
                                               typeof(int).MakeByRefType()
                                           });

// use it
var parameters = new object[] { "1", null };
var success = (bool)tryParseMethod.Invoke(null, parameters);
var result = (int)parameters[1];
```

Comment: Yep. Note that `nameof()` requires C# 6.0

Comment: Voting for this answer for suggesting nameof instead of a string.