# Unchecked assignment in generic function

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to write a generic method to perform an unchecked assignment from a long to other type.  Here is the simplified version:

```
    private static void AssignHex<T>(string hex, out T val) where T : struct 
    {
        if (long.TryParse(hex, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier, null, out long lval))
        {
            unchecked
            {
                val = (T)Convert.ChangeType(lval, typeof(T));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            val = default(T);
        }
    }
```

This works fine except for input string "FFFFFFFF" and type int where I expect to get -1 and instead get overflow exception.  The equivalent non-generic method works fine:

```
    private static void AssignHex2(string hex, out int val)
    {
        if (long.TryParse(hex, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier, null, out long lval))
        {
            unchecked
            {
                val = (int)lval;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            val = default(int);
        }
    }
```

I can simply write non-generics but it bothers me that I can't get the generic version to work.  Any solution?

Comment: Why do you expect `-1` from this? If you do, then perhaps you need to be using `int.TryParse` instead?

Comment: Exception is thrown by `Convert.ChangeType`, but not by conversion.

Comment: Yes, @DavidG, that is what I get from non-generic.  I want generic to work.

Comment: Indeed @PetSerAl, but what else will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  Some pain was involved, but here is the answer:

```
    private static bool AssignHex4<T>(string hex, out T val)
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);
        MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("TryParse", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(NumberStyles), typeof(IFormatProvider), typeof(T).MakeByRefType()});
        if (mi != null)
        {
            object[] parameters = new object[] {hex, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier, null, null};
            object result = mi.Invoke(null, parameters);
            if ((bool) result)
            {
                val = (T)parameters[3];
                return true;
            }
        }

        val = default(T);
        return false;
    }
```

Shout outs are required to a few SO answers that were instrumental in putting this together:

[MethodInfo.Invoke with out Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569249/methodinfo-invoke-with-out-parameter)

[Specifying out params for Type.GetMethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515642/specifying-out-params-for-type-getmethod)

I'll admit it is not a particularly elegant answer, but I think it is *comprehensive* and that is what I was looking for.

Consider...

```
        AssignHex4("FF", out byte r1);
        AssignHex4("FFFF", out short r2);
        AssignHex4("FFFFFFFF", out int r3);
        AssignHex4("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF", out long r4);
        AssignHex4("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF", out BigInteger r5);
        Console.WriteLine("Convert in reflection function returns:" + r1 + ", " + r2 + ", " + r3 + ", " + r4 + ", " + r5);
```

results in...

```
Convert in reflection function returns:255, -1, -1, -1, -1
```

Answer (score 4):

While `System.Convert.ChangeType` is really handy a lot of times but you cannot use it in your scenario. `FFFFFFFF` in decimal is ‭4294967295 which cannot be represented in `int` type and conversion fails. Specific code that throws is [this](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/shared/System/Convert.cs#L1164) (there is a check if long is larger than maximal `int` value).

If you want this functionality, then you will have to manually write similar code as is in `System.Convert.ChangeType` - `if` statements on different possible types with appropriate casts wrapped in `unchecked` block. Or simply not use generics and have overload for each type that you are interested in.

EDIT: It may be better to remove `unchecked` blocks altogether and parse hex value directly to appropriate type instead of parsing it first to long. This way you will directly parse it to expected value and receive error if value is out of range instead of just silently ignoring leftover bits with `unchecked` block.

EDIT2: Negative numbers are represented using [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). In short you can get negative number from positive by flipping all bits which represent positive number and adding 1. This means that binary or hex representation of negative number depends on how many bits are allocated for a number. So for 8 bit number (`sbyte`) -1 is 0xFF, for 16 bit number (`short`) is 0xFFFF, for 32 bit number (`int`) is 0xFFFFFFFF and for 64 bit number (`long`) is 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. Since you are parsing hex value 0xFFFFFFFF as `long` this is not -1, since you are actually parsing 0x0000000FFFFFFFF. What your `unchecked` block does is that when casting to lower precision number it will just take as many bits as required for lower precision type and discard the rest without any checks. Imagine now that you have 0XF0000000FFFFFFFF. If you parse this as long you get ~ -1 quintillion but with unchecked cast to `int` you would get -1, totally ignoring the most significant 4 bits.

Comment: FFFFFFFF absolutely can be represented in an int type as -1 and this is what I expect.

Comment: FFFFFFFF can be represented in int as -1, but you have parsed it as long, not as int. Since you parsed it as long, it is 4294967295 and not -1, and 4294967295 cannot be represented as int. Either parse it directly as int from hex or write code with unchecked blocks.

Comment: Ok @nejcs lets look at this problem another way.  How do you express -1 as hex?

Comment: @AQuirky Updated answer.

Comment: I know what 2's compliment is.  You haven't answered the question.  I want a generic method to move a hex value into either byte, char, int or long as appropriate.  I'm not using long.TryParse...I put that in the question simply to make it straightforward but apparently it has confused you.  The answer will be a generic method that does uses only T and does not contain int, long or any other explicit type.  I'm looking for elegance here.  I already have a method that has a bunch if if-then-else clauses and I am trying to do better.

Comment: I am well aware of your intentions and I have answered you. Since you don't like my answer, maybe somebody else will give you one that you will like.